# How can I test if a page object yml file has duplicate keys using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given a yml file with

```
thing1: 'thing1'
thing2: 'thing2'
thing3: 'first'
thing3: 'second'
thing4: 'thing4'
thing5: 'thing5'
thing5: 'thing5'
thing6: 'thing6'
```

How can I write an rspec test that fails if there are duplicate keys as shown? Duplicate values is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a test to see if each key (locator name) occurs more than once

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'Page Objects locator yml file' do
  it 'does not have duplicates' do
    file = File.open('locators.yml')
    pairs = []
    keys = []

    file.each_line do |line|
      words = line.split(': ')
      pairs << {words[0] => words[1]}
      keys << words[0]
    end 
    file.close

    if keys.uniq.count != keys.count
      p "Duplicate Page Object key(s) found: #{keys.uniq.count} unique vs #{keys.count} total"
      p 'dupe keys:'
      dupe_keys = keys.select{|n| keys.count(n) > 1}.uniq
      dupe_keys.each do |key|
        pairs.each do |pair|
          p "#{key.to_sym} : #{pair[key]}" if pair[key]
        end 
      end 
    end 

    expect(keys.uniq.count).to (eq keys.count),
      lambda {"Duplicate page object keys found! #{dupe_keys}"}

  end 
end
```